# django 1.8 model field permits blank but is required

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have some model fields for which values should be optional.  As per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#null), I set blank but not null.  `Manage.py makemigrations` says I need a default value even though it's empty, no problem:

```
address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
```

And yet when I use this in a form, form validation comes back with "this field is required".

The form looks like this:

```
address = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
```

And the solution was simply that the form needed to look like this instead:

```
address = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=False)
```

See the doc link at the beginning of the second sentence for why using `null=True` is not the right thing to do.

Comment: Can you show the form?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to clearly understand the difference between :
null = True and blank = True.

null = true, is used when the value of a particular field is optional. 
blank = true, is used when the value of the field is to be rendered as **'required'** field while using it in forms.

They are together used for certain fields to ensure that, the particular field's value is optional. So here, instead of using **blank=True**, enforce **null=True** to make the value for **first_name** optional.

Comment: Did you see the comment in the docs that I linked?  The recommendation is to use empty strings rather than null's for missing string values in order to avoid having two types of non-values.

Comment: Are you using a ModelForm? Can you post your form code here?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, the form field should be flagged with `required=False`.  I've updated the question to show the corrected line in full.

[reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#required)